# docker compose mount host directory on osx with xhyve

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

So my problem is related to mounting host computer directories from my osx macbook into the container running inside the machine.

In my previous company they used devops and we were using docker with virtualbox and what I noticed what that they used VBoxManage to mount directories into the docker machine and from there mounted those folders into the containers.

However, now that I am not using virtualbox, but xhyve virtual machine I am wondering how I can access host directories inside my containers.

I want to host databases and codebases, hosting them inside nginx containers, then when the code is on the host computer, use IDEA to edit the code, which then gives me a working platform.

However, whenever I follow the instructions I think should work, it does not appear to work correctly.

For example, my nginx configuration is like this:

```
FROM nginx:latest
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

And my docker compose is like this:

```
version: "2"
services:
  nginx_php:
    build: docker/nginx
    ports:
      - "10000:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/test
```

Now when I do a docker-compose up, then shell into the docker container using "docker exec -it  bash" I can list directories and find /var/test and it contains SOMETHING, but not what I expect.

For example, in the "." directory I used in the volumes statement in my docker compose, I do have a directory called projects and in /dev/test in the docker container, I do find projects.

However, I dont find "stacks" which is just an old left over directory, doesnt matter what it is, but I dont find it, so it appears to have mounted "." but its not displaying everything, just certain things.

So I took this one step further, I created a directory called "angi" before this process and if I list the contents of projects I can see angi directory as I expected.

So taking it another step further, I created a directory called "monkey", but when I rebuild the containers and start them up again, I can see "/projects/angi" but I cannot see "/projects/monkey"

So wtf....its like it is mounting half of the filesystem, or selectively showing me certain parts, or something like that, I am unsure how to mount host directories now because I dont get results that I expect.

Does anybody know what might be going wrong?

Comment: I didn't find a solution to my problem, apart from stop using the old docker and use Docker for Mac instead, I have described the problem in this github: https://github.com/zchee/docker-machine-driver-xhyve/issues/136

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in the same boat.  I have docker/docker-machine/docker-machine-driver-xhyve installed (via homebrew) and have this same issue.

I think what's happening is, you're creating a volume on the host - which in this case is the docker-machine, and not your mac os host.  I think there needs to be another jump... How that happens, I'm not sure.

But I can confirm, using the garden variety clean docker app takes care of this for you.

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel pointed out MacOS Docker container volume is mounted not to host MacOS, but to intermediate VM.

So there's two options

You can copy content you need to VM using (if your VM named default)

```
docker-machine scp [localfiles] default:./
```

Or you can do additional step semiautomatic by using sshfs:

```
docker-machine mount default:[/mountpoint] [localpath]
```

Second option will require sshfs which is available from brew

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
brew cask install osxfuse
brew install sshfs
```

More details are at https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/mount/

Also be careful as it's one way sync option. If you need to get something from machine be sure you scped it back.